# Extract whole word from string

Tags: swift, string, substring

I have a string like:

> I need glass in California

For extracting "glass" (or anything) between word "need" and "in" I am using this method:

```
let category = "I need glass in California".substring(from: "need", to: "in", options: .caseInsensitive)


extension StringProtocol  {
    func substring<S: StringProtocol, T: StringProtocol>(from start: S, to end: T, options: String.CompareOptions = []) -> SubSequence? {
        guard let lower = range(of: start, options: options)?.upperBound,
            let upper = self[lower...].range(of: end, options: options)?.lowerBound
            else { return nil }
        return self[lower..<upper]
    }
}
```

For this String : > I need paint in California

If I need to extract "paint" keyword it pick only "pa" as "in" keyword is also present in paint (pa'in't)

I am in need to get the whole word PAINT, the method is going through every characters of string

Comment: You need to extract "paint" from where?

Comment: Why don't you just use the components-separated function of String??

Comment: If you are trying to extract meaning or intent from the sentences consider using NLTokenizer https://developer.apple.com/documentation/naturallanguage/nltokenizer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fast solution to keep using your algorithm is to search for substrings between " need " and " in ". Spaces before and after are important and will force a whole word search.